# When adding click handlers to list items in jQuery, they all trigger immediately

Tags: jquery, click, handler

In the following code I'm rendering a list of projects, each item of which will perform an action relevant to its associated project object when clicked.  However, when I run the code, the alerts all show up at once on page load, and then don't show up when the list item is clicked.  What am I doing wrong?

```
var projects = (an array of project objects)

jQuery.each(projects, function(index, project) {
    jQuery("#project-list").append("<li "+classString+"><a>"+project.title+"</a></li>");
    jQuery("#project-list").find("li:last").click( function() {
                        alert(project.title);
                    });
    });
```

Comment: What does you html look like? can you make a little demo on http://jsfiddle.net ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to whip up the following which does, to my knowledge, what you're attempting:

```
var projects = [{title:'Project 1'},{title:'Project 2'}];

$.each(projects, function(i){
  $("<a/>", { href:'#', text:projects[i].title })
    .click(function(e){alert( projects[i].title );})
    .wrap("<li></li>")
    .parent()
    .appendTo("#project-list");
});
```

I was merely guessing on the object structure for your projects, but you could modify this. I'm not sure why your clicks would have been happening automatically; mine work fine in the above code sample. Perhaps there's something else invoking them that isn't present in the code you posted here.

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/uhixac/edit

Comment: Now it's working fine, and I can't reproduce the earlier problem even though it was persistent an hour ago.  I'm no wiser, but thanks for the effort...

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect an extra pair of braces:

```
(...).click(function() {
    //...
}()); // note the extra braces here
```

This executes your click handler immediately and passes the return value (`undefined`) to `jQuery.click` (which triggers a simulated click event, doing nothing) instead of binding the click handler to the click event.

Comment: @Tgr- thanks for the effort- It's working now, not sure what happened